# Finding the Green's function of the Wave Equation (with no time dependence)

Tags: electromagnetism, differential-equations

Imagine you want to  find a potential given the following equation:
$$
\square \phi (t, \mathbf r) = 4\pi \delta^3(\mathbf r) \\ \; \\
\phi(0, \mathbf r)= 0\\ \; \\
\partial_t\phi(0, \mathbf r)= 0
$$
Using the Fourier Transform,
$$
\mathcal F\{ \square \phi - 4\pi \delta^3(\mathbf r) \} =0 
$$
We get:
$$
\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2 \Phi}{\partial^2t} + k^2 \Phi = 4 \pi
$$
Solving:
$$
\Phi(t, \mathbf k) = A(\mathbf  k)e^{ic|k|t} + B(\mathbf  k)e^{-ic|k|t} + \frac{4\pi}{k^2}\\ \; \\ \; \\
\phi(t, \mathbf r) = \int_{\mathbb R^3} d^3\mathbf k \; e^{i \mathbf k\cdot\mathbf r} \left [A(\mathbf  k)e^{ic|k|t} + B(\mathbf  k)e^{-ic|k|t} + \frac{4\pi}{k^2} \right] 
$$
But I'm stuck, how I'm supposed to follow and find $\phi(t, \mathbf r)$ purely in terms of $t$ and $\mathbf r$. How can I solve the integral?

Comment: You solve for $A,B$ by matching the initial conditions. Btw, they are incomplete, you’d also need to specify $\partial_t\phi(t=0)$ for example

Comment: Yeah, my fault, sorry...

Comment: is $\delta^3(\mathbf r)$ intended to be $\delta^3(x)\delta^3(y)\delta^3(z)$ ?